# ORACLE sql Explicitly providing values in a WHERE clause showing much better performance compared to using sub query

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

I am new to oracle

I have 2 tables to join 
huge_table contains about 1 billion rows
big_table contains about 100 million rows
and small tables contains 999 rows providing the condition to filter

The the small_table.num_id to match huge_table.num_id column

The problem I noticed is if I explicitly provide the values in where clauses it will be much faster compared using sub query .

Specifically when looking at the explain plan result 
This query is much faster with cardinality of 100 and cost of 6

```
SELECT h.col_required, b.col_required, h.num_id
FROM  huge_table h,
      big_table b
WHERE h.row_id = b.xx_id
  AND b.status = 'up'
  AND h.num_id in ('num1', 'num2',... 'num100')  -- Explicitly providing the values that in 
                                                 -- small_table`
```

This query with sub query is much slower with cardinality of 1445704 and cost of 660293

```
SELECT h.col_required, b.col_required, h.num_id
FROM huge_table h, big_table b
WHERE h.row_id = b.xx_id
  AND b.status = 'up'
  AND h.num_id in ('SELECT num_id FROM small_table)  -- Using sub query 
                                                     -- provide the values
```

I also tried using WHERE exits or INNER JOIN the small_table both providing the similar result with sub query.

The question I have is if it is possible to have good performance without explicitly providing the values in where clause?

Thanks

I finally find out the reasons caused this issue.

In the small_table the datatype for num_id is NVARCHAR2(255)
Whilst in the huge_table the datatype for num_id  is VARCHAR2(255).

Basically after I converted the datatype the query time reduced.

Comment: Can you try changing the last line to: `AND exists (SELECT 1 from small_table where num_id = h.num_id)`? Is that any better?

Comment: @zedfoxus Usually `WHERE IN` and `WHERE EXISTS` get optimized to the same thing under the hood.  But it's still worth trying your suggestion.

Comment: Are the data types the same, h1.num_id is the same data type as num_id from small_table? Both varchar2, based in query 1.

Comment: Maybe try an index hint to force the  in  clause ahead of the join, probably not that but something to try.

Comment: For query performance, step 1 is _always_ to capture the query plans

Answer (score 0):

This answer is speculative, but one possible explanation for the performance you are seeing is that Oracle is executing the subquery in the `WHERE` clause multiple times in the second query.  That is, rather than executing it once and caching the result set, the work is being done several times over.  If you rewrite the query using an explicit join, it might get around this problem:

```
SELECT h.col_required, b.col_required, h.num_id
FROM huge_table h
INNER JOIN big_table b
    ON h.row_id = b.xx_id
INNER JOIN small_table s
    ON h.num_id = s.num_id
WHERE
    b.status = 'up';
```

You also may add the following index on `num_id` to the `small_table`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON small_table (num_id);
```

This might help Oracle do the second join/lookup more quickly.

Comment: Thanks my initial query is using inner join which gives me the cardinality of 5765186 and cost of 660780.

Comment: Did you test my exact answer though?  I suggest also adding an index to `num_id` in the small table.  This by itself could mean the difference between good and bad performance.

Comment: Hi, Tim I created index on small table, and unique index to num_id which gives me cardinality of 5765186 and cost 660223 similar to without index.

Comment: I'm beginning to think now that maybe strange things are happening given the very large size of your tables.  I would have expected at least a few of the suggestions already given to improve things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `exists`:

```
SELECT h.col_required, b.col_required, h.num_id
FROM huge_table h join
     big_table b
     on h.row_id = b.xx_id
WHERE b.status = 'up' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM small_table st
              WHERE h.num_id = st.num_id
             );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `small_table(num_id)`, as well as whatever other indexes you have on the other tables.

Comment: Thanks I tried WHERE EXITS too, this result gives me the cardinality of 1 and cost of 4270291 not as good as explicitly provide the value